Angular 18, VS Code 1.95.2, after ng serve, hitting F5 starts the browser and spins indefinitely

After issuing "ng serve"
Application bundle generation complete. [6.875 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
NOTE: Raw file sizes do not reflect development server per-request transformations.
➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
➜  press h + enter to show help
If I do CTRL-F5 the app starts fine but I can't debug it at all.  When I try F5, the browser starts with a blank page and it spins indefinitely.
I tried changing port, I also tried the basics like Restarting the PC ;), npm cache clean, deleted dist folder, deleted node_modules folder, npm install
When I go to my branch 17 it works just fine but since I opted to use the new build system, I get this issue
Any ideas what I can try next ?

I temporarily reverted to the previous build system which works until a solution is found here.

For reference
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/28847
